# Отношение людей и закона ко взлому

Tags: взлом, авторские-права, юридические-аспекты

Например, я случайно или преднамеренно взломал чужой сайт (возьмем некоторый сферический в вакууме), но ничего не сделал, а сразу сообщил администрации, что сайт обладает такими-то ошибками, которые они бы могли исправить и так далее (полностью безвозмездно).

Как относится закон в России, Украине, Европе к подобным (теперь оговоримся четко) планомерным действиям?

Как отнесется ХэшКод к такому действию? И соответственно, пользователи, что вы думаете по этому поводу, как бы вы отреагировали (прошу рассматривать не только с точки зрения чувств, а еще и логики, ведь я могу быть и хуже, а "отдать" данные нескольких тысяч пользователей в чужие руки, согласитесь, кто бы согласился)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Закон против, а юзеры - зависит от вашего поведения напрямую) Если сайт серьезный коммерческий - скорее всего за дырку не обломаются даже заплатить, если визитка - будут выпрашивать. Но если просто "сломали и рассказали" - скорее всего будет как минимум "спасибо".

По закону взлом сам по себе преступление(статью не дам, но это вроде логично). Ну, если вы не работаете в этой компании - но тогда это "тестирование безопасности".

Откуда - скажем, опыт (не мой, мне только "спасибо" было)) Если собираетесь продавать дыры - позаботьтесь об анонимности запроса и оплаты, иначе вами может заняться СБ, а если обороты сайта высоки - то и исход я прогнозировать не буду. На рынке много ребят из 90х :)

Comment: Вот как раз больше интересует мнение как разработчика. Т.е. я вот такой Фдеот, сломал вашу защиту, сообщил вам об этом. А вы вместо элементарного "спасибо" сразу за УК взялись, юристов пригласили и прочее. Как тогда быть мне? Какие у меня шансы?

Ведь если я мог запросто сделать вообще гадость. Я уж молчу про банки, разного рода сервисы с деньгами и тому подобное.

Comment: Если вам на простое сообщение отвечают, что "вас посадят/пристрелят/съедят", нууу... Олдовые хакеры высыпали на сервак 300-метровую коллекцию вирей и троянов) Скажем, я бы их ломал полностью и жег железо) Но - шанс так нарваться, конечно, есть, люди вообще часто не отличаются адекватностью.

Просто пишите с анонимной почты. Например, у hidemyass такой сервис есть.

Comment: Логично! На самом деле, ничего взламывать не собираюсь, просто интересно стало.

Answer (score 2):

Законы в этом плане - вообще не понятны... Мне во всяком случае.
А как я отношусь к этому? Честь Вам и хвала за это! Ведь вы делаете мой(любой другой) сайт лушче и надежнее, причем совершенно бесплатно!

Answer (score 1):

С юридической точки зрения - это преступление - неправомерный доступ к компьютерной информации. А вот с точки пользователя это действительно может быть разное мнение.

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны - это бесплатный аудит безопасности, с другой - ... вполне возможен вариант, что "хакер" выложит вам далеко не все найденные им дыры, просто усыпив тем самым вашу бдительность (хотя, люди, которые после подобных сообщений о проблемах не проводят полного профессионального аудита системы, вызывают как минимум удивление).

Answer (score 1):

вообще-то по закону взлом сайта (или другого обьекта) это еще не преступление. преступление наступает когда вы пользуясь этим совершаете несанкционированный доступ к какой-либо информации на взломаном обьекте

это теория, - то как должно быть, а на самом деле взломав что-то для "нашего правосудия" вы уже стали преступником. скорее за все даже не потому что вы опасны, а просто потому что им нужны люди которые будут бесплатно на них работать. ведь запугав вас можно легко заставить работать на них под прикрытием, - это судьба многих тру "кул-хацкеров"

вы сообщили администрации, если "по ту сторону экрана":
1. адекватные люди - они скажут вам спасибо, в лучшем дадут вам вознаграждение или даже наймут консультантом
2. неадекватные люди - начнут угрожать "правосудием", в если у них достаточно связей то вы станете обьектом интереса спецслужб